# r write list to table

Tags: r, list

I have a list as below:

```
l1=list()
l1[[1]]="YES"
l1[[2]]="NO"
l1
> l1
[[1]]
[1] "YES"

[[2]]
[1] "NO"
```

I want to write it to a table (something like `write.table(answer, row.names = F, col.names = F)`). Please note - output shouldn't have any "" and each element on a new line.

The table should have:

```
YES
NO
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these should work for you

```
x <- list("YES", "NO")

write.table(do.call(rbind, x), quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
# YES
# NO
cat(unlist(x), sep = "\n")
# YES
# NO
```

There are `file` arguments in each of these functions for writing to file.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `data.table`?

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)

l1 <- data.table(l1)

> l1
l1
#1: YES
#2:  NO
```